# Linear Algebra - Which of the following sets is a subspace of $M_{3\times3}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Which of the following sets is a subspace of $M_{33}$,
1) $S=\{A∈M_{33} : \mathcal N(A)\ni e_1\}$
2) $S=\{A∈M_{33} : \det(A)=0\}$
3) $S=\{A∈M_{33} :A^{\tau}A=I_3\}$
4) $S=\{A∈M_{33} :A \text{ is diagonalizable} \}$

The answer is $A$, could anyone give me the explanation?

Comment: Can you show what you have done so far?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I know that for 2) it means A is not invertible 3) means A is orthogonal. Seems not related to vector space? But I don't know what 1) means.

Comment: In 1) $S$ is just all matrices $A$ with $Ae_1=0$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy could you give me more details? What is so special about the vector ${1,0,0}$

Comment: @keanehui Nothing's special with $\;e_1\;$ : just prove that set is closed under sum of vectors and product by scalar, that's all.

Comment: The first thing I look for in the "is this a vector space?" question, is it closed under addition?  e.g. can I find two singular matrices that sum to a non-singular matrix?  If I can then it is not a vector space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hints:**

**For (1):** 
If $A, B \in S$, this means $Ae_1=0$ and $Be_1=0$. Then $Ae_1+Be_1=0+0=0 \implies (A+B)e_1=0$. This shows that the sum of the matrices $A$ and $B$ is also in $S$ (hence $S$ is closed under addition). Now you can check if $S$ is closed under multiplication by a scalar.

**For (2):**
 Try with $A=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$ and $B=\begin{bmatrix}0&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$. What can you say about the sum $A+B$?

Hopefully you can take it from here.

Comment: is it correct that detA=0,detB=0, det(A+B) is not 0, so it is not a subspace of $M_{3\times3}$ ?

Comment: @keanehui yes that's correct?